# Node.js MySQL create Table dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm having trouble creating a table with dynamically amount of columns.

I have an Object, **where i don't know the amount of keys exactly**:

```
var obj = {
  data_1: 123,
  data_2: 456,
  data_3: 789,
  (...)
};
```

Each key of this Object should become a column in the new table.
Fortunately, the column datatype is always a double.

I need something like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE 'Data' (  
   FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES other_table(id), // this is fixed
   data_0 int, // this is fixed
   Object.keys(obj) double
)"
```

Is this even possible? I could find nothing that looks similar to this.

I'd be really glad, if someone could help me out with this one.

Comment: Save it as a JSON object into the DB instead?

Comment: is this the only possibility? I'd rather have a column for each value.

Comment: Are you sure all objects have the exact same keys. If it is you can generate that portion of the *create table* with something than `Object.keys(data).map(k=>k+" int,\n")`.

Comment: This can't be really answered without knowing the exact use case, and all edge cases of how you work with the data. In general, if you don't know the number of `data_` entries, and you need to be able to query the data stored for `data_`  then you need to have a table in the form `other_table(id), key, value`  and each  `data_` is an own row in the table. If you have a maximum number of keys per entry, then you can think about  columns than can be NULL.

Comment: @bitifet this works perfectly. thanks! didn't actually knew that you can "loop" inside an sql statement using map. if you could post it as an actual answer i will mark is as accepted. my statement (which is working) looks like this now:  `"CREATE TABLE new_table (ID int, FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES other_table (ID), data_0 int, "+ Object.keys(obj).map(k=>k+" double")+")"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually solved in comments.

But for the sake of completion, here it is more detailed:

If all objects to be inserted have the same keys, we can pick the keys from the first one and use that data to generate the whole *CREATE TABLE* statement.

Example:

```
const data = require("path/to/some/data");
const sql = [
  "CREATE TABLE new_table (",
  "id int REFERENCES other_table (id),",
  "data_0 int,",
  Object.keys(data[0])
    .map(k=>k+" int")
    .join("\n")
  ,
  ")",
].join("\n");
```